How do I generate Kotlin's type from gradle task?
I am writing a gradle task in one of my projects, this task needs to write a kotlin file.
def fileSpec = FileSpec.builder(packageName.toLowerCase(), "ModelClass")
                .addType(
                        TypeSpec.classBuilder("Model")
                                .primaryConstructor(
                                        FunSpec.constructorBuilder()
                                                .addParameter("name",String.class )
                                                .build()
                                )
                                .addProperty(
                                        PropertySpec.builder("name", String.class)
                                                .initializer("name")
                                                .build()
                                )
                                .build()
                )
                .build()
        def kotlinFile = new File(dir, "ModelClass.kt")
        kotlinFile.withWriter('UTF-8') {
            writer ->
                fileSpec.writeTo(writer)
        }

The task completes without any error but the generated class code lacks kotlin type.
import java.lang.String

public class Model(
  public val name: String,
)

The generated class imports String from the java.lang instead of Kotlin Std Lib. My gradle task is written in groovy ( I had to choose groovy because my IDE always complains "code insightful is not available" in the custom gradle.kts file). I guess, we can't generate kotlin file from non-kotlin file or can we?

kotlin.String doesn't really exist at runtime, it compiles down to java.lang.String, so when you're trying to access its type using reflection (i.e. String::class) you get java.lang.String.
The easiest way around it is to use the STRING property defined by KotlinPoet. You can also create your own ClassName if you want: ClassName("kotlin", "String").
